# On click, toggle class outside of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script that toggles the elements within a parent element however, I need to also toggle any other elements outside the parent separately. Not entirely sure how to do that. This is what I have so far:

```js
$('.card-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings('.card-img, .card-text').toggle(250);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="img.jpg" data-location="local">
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="card-toggle">Domy</button>
  </div>
  <p class="card-text">
    <span style="font-size:0.9em">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: So if you want any element that's not in the current `.card`, just use `$('.card-img, .card-text').toggle(250);`

Comment: see the bottom of this page: http://app.tendesign.us/sites/ohio-cashflow/about using `code`$('.card-img, .card-text').toggle(250); in addition to my code above causes an undesired effect. basically I am trying to have the button click trigger opening the current card and close any other cards that may be open.

Comment: first of all, it doesn't toggle elements within the parent, but the siblings of the parent. secondly, how do you want it to work on other elements? please explain your scenario thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use target all `card-toggle` using class selector excluding current element using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and perform desired operation on them.

```
$('.card-toggle').not(this).parent().siblings('.card-img, .card-text').hide(250);
```

```js
$('.card-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings('.card-img, .card-text').toggle(250);
  
  $('.card-toggle').not(this).parent().siblings('.card-img, .card-text').hide(250);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="img.jpg" data-location="local">
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="card-toggle">Domy</button>
  </div>
  <p class="card-text">
    <span style="font-size:0.9em">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="img.jpg" data-location="local">
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="card-toggle">Domy</button>
  </div>
  <p class="card-text">
    <span style="font-size:0.9em">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can also use

```
var siblings = $(this).parent().siblings('.card-img, .card-text');  
siblings.toggle(250);  
$('.card-img, .card-text').not(siblings).hide(250);
```

```js
$('.card-toggle').on('click', function() {
  var siblings = $(this).parent().siblings('.card-img, .card-text');  
  siblings.toggle(250);  
  $('.card-img, .card-text').not(siblings).hide(250);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="img.jpg" data-location="local">
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="card-toggle">Domy</button>
  </div>
  <p class="card-text">
    <span style="font-size:0.9em">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="img.jpg" data-location="local">
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="card-toggle">Domy</button>
  </div>
  <p class="card-text">
    <span style="font-size:0.9em">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate</span>
  </p>
</div>
```